# CodeIgniter 3 session confusion

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Working on upgrade to CodeIgniter **3**, and encountering some issues with the Session class.

We are configured for storing the session in the database. We have set up the proper `ci_sessions` table and have this in Config.php:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 600;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
```

Trying to store session data with `$this->session->set_userdata($data);`

With the above we get an error indicating CI is not reading the table name from the "sess_save_path" variable:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET `last_activity` = 1437070556, `user_data` = 'a:14:{s:9:\\"user_data\\";s:0:\\"\' at line 1
>
> UPDATE  SET `last_activity` = 1437070556,

As you can see the table name is missing between UPDATE and SET

To fix this, I went into Config.php and added the old deprecated method of setting the table name that you aren't supposed to use anymore:

```
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
```

This works better, but I get a new error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'session_id' in 'where clause'
>
> UPDATE `ci_sessions` SET `last_activity` = 1437075587, `user_data` = 'a:14:{ [SESSION DATA REMOVED FROM EXAMPLE]  }'
>
> WHERE `session_id` = '636c6c7389342a7a21111e3e2c3c3f03'
>
> Filename: libraries/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 306

What is going on and how do I fix it? Why doesn't `$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';` work? What's the deal with the `session_id` field?

**EDIT:**

After more testing, I conclude:

`$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';` doesn't work

`$this->session->set_userdata($data);` doesn't work

`$this->session->set_userdata('name', $data);` doesn't work

`$_SESSION['name'] = $data` works

Is the CI3 documentation horribly inaccurate, or is something else wrong?

**EDIT 2:**

New additional problem:

```
$this->load->library('session');
$data = $_SESSION['data'];
```

throws `Undefined variable: _SESSION`. My initial impression is that, in any given function, I have to write to $_SESSION before I can read from $_SESSION

Comment: What is the output of the MySQL command `DESC ci_sessions` ?  It is trying to run the query but telling you no such column `session_id` exists which it needs for its session storage.  Does not sound like the session table is properly defined.

Comment: @drew010, the official table definition for the ci_sessions table does not call for a session_id column. Further, I can store session data if I use the new $_SESSION superglobal, but not with the old method that is supposed to still work

Comment: See my answer below about why it is using `session_id`.  That probably means the session code being used is not using the latest CI3 session library.  If you look at the code of [CI2 session](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/2.2-stable/system/libraries/Session.php#L270) it uses `session_id`, [CI3 sessions](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_database_driver.php#L211) uses `id`, so the library code being run is CodeIgniter2 not 3 hence the sql error.

Comment: @halfer After the question being on hold and seeing the idiotic typo I made in the very title, I became embarrassed enough to delete the question entirely. However, I've just undeleted it for you. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something strange is going on with the code.

According to the CodeIgniter3 docs for the [session database configuration](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver), the session table needs to be initialized with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
        `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
        `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        `data` blob NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id),
        KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

Based on your error the `session_id` column does not exist which is not what CodeIgniter3 is using.  Is your code somehow still loading the CI2 session code?  I downloaded the latest version of CI3 and in the `Session_database_driver::write()` function it makes the following call:

```
        $insert_data = array(
            'id' => $session_id,
            'ip_address' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
            'timestamp' => time(),
            'data' => ($this->_platform === 'postgre' ? base64_encode($session_data) : $session_data)
        );
```

As you can see there is no trace of the `session_id` column.

Comment: It appears another dev left the old CI 2 session class in the system directory when he brought in the new CI 3 class, so we were getting conflicts between the two. Thanks Drew

Comment: @user45623 Happy to help! Glad that was it.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem after moving form codeigniter 2 to 3. I solved it with replacing "system" folder with the new one, which comes with CI3

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and solved it by deleting the system folder and replacing it with the original from the CI3 zip. I overwrote it previously due to an upgrade but still had this error.